# Creating random numbers without duplicates in Perl/CGI

Tags: perl, random, cgi

This is my current code:

```
sub randompass {
srand(time ^ $$);
my @passset = ('a'..'k', 'm'..'n', 'p'..'z', '2'..'9');
my $randpass = "";
for (my $i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
    $randpass .= $passset[int(rand($#passset + 1))];
}
return $randpass;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how your code isn't working?

Comment: What is your question? My telepathy isn't working well today.

Comment: Loop contents possibly more readably written as `$randpass .= $passset[ rand @passset ];`

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `srand();` and you'll get expected behavior of `rand()`

from [`perldoc -f srand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html)

> If srand() is not called explicitly, it is called implicitly without a parameter at the first use of the rand operator. However, there are a few situations where programs are likely to want to call srand. **One is for generating predictable results**, generally for testing or debugging.